# Sending JSON data stored in a struct through a segue

Tags: ios, swift, api, struct, segue

I'm wanting to store "idMeal" on the cell I click to send it through a segue to my DetailViewController and use it to access an API endpoint for the respective meal.

[API](https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Dessert)

[API with meal details that I'm trying to access for EACH meal when clicked on.](https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=52897)

I believe I'm very close but I've been here for several hours.

Here are my structs:

```
//struct for the dictionary holding the desserts
struct DessertDictionary: Codable {
    var meals: [Desserts]
}

//struct for all desserts
struct Desserts: Codable {
    var strMeal: String?
    var strMealThumb: String?
    var idMeal: String?

}
//struct for dictionary holding the details
struct MealDataDictionary: Codable {
    var meals: IndependentMealData
}

//struct for dessert details
struct IndependentMealData: Codable {
    var idMeal: String
    var strMeal: String
    var strInstructions: String
}
```

Here is my first ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    var mealList = [Desserts]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        getApiData {
            print("data loaded")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mealList.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(mealList[indexPath.row].strMeal!)"
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? DetailTableViewController {
            destination.idMeal = //NEED DATA HERE//
        }
    }
    
    
//    MealApi.shared.getApiData(onCompletion: anonFunction)
    func getApiData(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Dessert")
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if error == nil {
                do {
                    // need to use the TopMeal struct to decode the json because it matches the structure of the json.
                    let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(DessertDictionary.self, from: data!)
                    // after you decode the json you access the array within it to setup your array of meals instance variable that is being used by your table view.
                    self.mealList = jsonData.meals
                    
                    

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Here is my DetailViewController where I am trying to pass the "idMeal" and use for the API pull for each cell, when clicked.

```
class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var idMeal: String = ""
    var mealDatails: IndependentMealData?
    
    
    //UI Oulets (Image, Dessert Name, Instructions, Ingredents)
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        func getApiDetailData(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
            let urlString = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?i=\(idMeal)"
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                
                if error == nil {
                    do {
                        // need to use the TopMeal struct to decode the json because it matches the structure of the json.
                        let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(MealDataDictionary.self, from: data!)
                        // after you decode the json you access the array within it to setup your array of meals instance variable that is being used by your table view.
                        self.mealDatails = jsonData.meals
//                        print(self.mealDatails?.idMeal)
                       
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completed()
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
```

If you need any extra information let me know, I've tried a number of things to access that data.

Comment: Just pass the `idMeal` as the `sender` instead of `self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to define the index the user tapped.
E.g., just save the row and use it.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
        
        var mealList = [Desserts]()
        var indexTapped: Int?

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
indexTapped = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
    }
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? DetailTableViewController {
                destination.idMeal = mealList[indexTapped!].idMeal
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate you providing the code, I never would of thought of this. However it gave this error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` Underlining indexTapped!

Comment: How does indexTapped store the number or index of which cell is tapped? I believe that's why its coming back nil.

Comment: @Googler indexTapped = indexPath.row <--- this line sets the proper value

Comment: @Googler it seems, I made a mistake. I've changed the answer

Comment: Thank you SO much! You just solved my headache for the day.

Comment: @Googler so approve this answer

Comment: Sorry man, just did. This is like my second post on here so not super familiar with all of it.